# Binary data stored in MySQL is getting corrupted with Node

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm using node-mysql2 and storing string-encoded binary data in MySQL. The column has a type of `binary(16)`. The data stored in MySQL is being corrupted, for example:

```
NodeJS output: 47 23 43 14 ed 86 14 dc 12 f3 b8 6c dc 31 fb fa
MySQL HEX()  : 47 23 43 14 c3 ad c2 86 14 c3 9c 12 c3 b3 c2 b8
```

Code:

```
var binaryString = randomBinaryString();
db.sqlQuery("INSERT INTO test(binaryString) VALUES(" + db.escape(binaryString) + ")");
console.log(new Buffer(binaryString, 'binary').toString('hex'));

function randomBinaryString(){
    var str = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        str += String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random()*256));
    }
    return str;
}
```

How should a string that actually encodes binary data (each character being a byte) be stored in MySQL using node-mysql2?

Answer (score 2):

You're not inserting a raw binary string but a UTF-8 encoded string. In UTF-8, codepoints after 127 are encoded using multiple bytes. The fifth byte `ed` (237) is encoded using 2 bytes.

`Buffer(String.fromCharCode(0xed))` produces : `<Buffer c3 ad>`

Sending the random string as a Buffer with binary encoding should fix the problem. `node-mysql` will convert the buffer to a hex string when inserting.

```
db.query('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?)', [ Buffer(randomString(), 'binary') ]);
```

Also, the `crypto` module has a `randomBytes` method that generates n random bytes.

```
db.query('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?)', [crypto.randomBytes(16)]);
```